# I keep getting the error "the specified string is not in the form required for an email address" when using Send-MailMessage

Tags: arrays, windows, email, powershell

```
#get max password age policy
$maxPwdAge=(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days

#expiring in 7 days
$7days=(get-date).AddDays(7-$maxPwdAge).ToShortDateString()

$EmailList = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * |
             where {($_.PasswordLastSet).ToShortDateString() -le $7days} |
             Select-Object EmailAddress

$EmailFrom = "code.example@email.com"
$EmailCc = "code.example2@email.com"

$EmailSubject = "Example subject"

$emailbody = "example body"
$SMTPServer = "192.168.8.130"

foreach ($element in $EmailList) {
  $output = Out-String -InputObject $element ;
  if ($finaloutput=$output.Contains(".")) {
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $output -Cc $EmailCc -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $emailbody -Bodyashtml;
  }
}
```

The first several lines run fine, however, when the `foreach` starts it errors out and says

> the specified string is not in the form required for an email address.

I am unsure why I get this error, because I have already converted the `$element` to a string using `Out-String`.

Comment: Add a line `"-$output-"` right after the `Out-String` statement. What is its output right before the error occurs?

Comment: My money is on `Select-Object EmailAddress` should be `Select-Object -Expand EmailAddress`. Looks like this in the loop I imagine `@{emailaddress=matt@notmdomain.ca}`

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: Instead of `-Property *`, use `-Property emailaddress` instead so you are not dragging down a lot of unnecessary properties. 
Related to your issue: Maybe also add a `Write-Verbose $Element -Verbose` in your code to see what is being displayed.

Comment: @boeprox Yes... that for sure. Huge waste of time pulling all those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$element` is not the email address, but an object that happens to have a property called `EmailAddress`.

`Out-String` just results in a multi-line string with the console output of `$element| Format-Table`.

Don't use `Out-String`, just refer to the `EmailAddress` property directly:

```
$output = $element.EmailAddress
```

Or, use `-as` to cast the address as a [`mailaddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) object. If the type check fails inside the `if()` statement, `Send-MailMessage` isn't executed.

```
if(($To = $element.EmailAddress -as [mailaddress])) {
    Send-MailMessage -To $To
}
```

---

To avoid the `Send-MailMessage` line getting too long, use a [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) table:

```
$MailParams = @{
    "From" = "code.example@email.com"
    "Cc"   = "code.example2@email.com"

    "Subject" = "Raw intelligence!"
    "Body"    = "Howdy! Here are some datez n stuff"

    "SmtpServer" = "192.168.8.130"
}
```

And then inside the loop:

```
Send-MailMessage -To $To @MailParams
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! However, now i get the error 5 times that "you cannot call a method on a null valued expression". I thought i had already ruled out null values via the contains if statement?

Comment: If `$output` is null you can just use `if($output){ do stuff}`. The Contains is the issue since Contains is a string method which null would not have access to.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am an intern with zero experience in powershell and this should impress my bosses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue here is that you expected `$element` to be an individual email address when it is in fact an object with an `emailaddress` property. Change the population of `$EmailList`:

```
$EmailList = ........ this remains the same |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress
```

Then your loop can be updated:

```
foreach ($element in $EmailList) {
  if ($finaloutput=$element.Contains(".")) {
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $element -Cc $EmailCc -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $emailbody -Bodyashtml;
  }
}
```

I don't see the point of `$finaloutput` but you don't need the middle man variable `$output` anymore. I would have done something similar to this:

```
$EmailList | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -From $EmailFrom -To $_ -Cc $EmailCc -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $emailbody -Bodyashtml
}
```

The `$_.Contains(".")` seems redundant but you get the picture. Using `Where-Object{$_}` we can filter nulls out since it is possible users would not have an email address. You could also move that logic to where you are populating  `$emaillist`.

Comment: For some reason this doesnt seem to work. It runs without errors but isnt sending any emails

Comment: @mplouque I have provided a couple of suggestions here so you have to help me more than _its not working_. Does `$EmailList` contain what you expect? Which code sample are you using since I gave 2?